# Oracle passing outer query value to inner query

Tags: sql, oracle

This might be a simple but I need to apply the logic  in other:

```
WITH t(col) AS (
SELECT 1 FROM dual
UNION SELECT 2 FROM dual
UNION SELECT 3 FROM dual
UNION SELECT 4 FROM dual
UNION SELECT 5 FROM dual
)
SELECT col , --- will works as usual
(SELECT col FROM t WHERE col  = outer_q.col) new_col,  --working as well
(
SELECT sum (latest_col)
from
(
SELECT col latest_col FROM t  WHERE col  = outer_q.col 
UNION ALL
SELECT col FROM t WHERE col   = outer_q.col
)
)newest_col   -- need to get an output "4"
from t outer_q where col  = 2;
```

An simple output like:

```
       COL    NEW_COL NEWEST_COL
---------- ---------- ----------
         2          2          4
```

I just need to use the outer most value to the inner I used for the third column

**EDITING**-- sample with more data:

```
WITH 
t(col) AS
     ( SELECT 1 FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 2 FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 3 FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 4 FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 5 FROM dual
     ),
t1(amount, col) AS
     (SELECT 100 , 2 FROM dual
     UNION
     SELECT 200, 3 FROM dual
     )
SELECT col,
     (SELECT col FROM t WHERE col = outer_q.col
     ) new_col,
     (SELECT SUM(x)
     FROM
          (SELECT col x FROM t
          UNION ALL
          SELECT amount x FROM t1
          )
     WHERE col = outer_q.col
     ) newest_col -- gives 315 as it takes whole `SUM`
FROM t outer_q
WHERE col = 2;
```

An output is expected like:

```
       COL    NEW_COL NEWEST_COL
---------- ---------- ----------
         2          2        102
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: :Seems wierd ,i am not able to understand ,why you are doing a union all in the inner part ,and you know that the sum of 2 and 2 is 4 ,dont understand the business behind this :(

Comment: haha. don't look that sum part or sample table, but look at the title, I just only need to pass the outer most query value to the inner. Hope its clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can if you refactor a but your query:

```
WITH t(col) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM dual
  UNION SELECT 2 FROM dual
  UNION SELECT 3 FROM dual
  UNION SELECT 4 FROM dual
  UNION SELECT 5 FROM dual
)
SELECT col,
       (SELECT col FROM t WHERE col  = outer_q.col) new_col,
       (SELECT sum (latest_col)
        from
        (
          SELECT col latest_col FROM t 
          UNION ALL
          SELECT col FROM t
        ) x
        where x.latest_col = outer_q.col
       ) newest_col   -- need to get an output "4"
from t outer_q where col = 2;
```

This is possible here because `outer_q` is now in the `where` clause of the sub-query. It was used before in the sub-sub-query (the one with the `UNION ALL`), and this one was hiding it.

To try to make things clearer, now we have something like:

```
with t as (...)
select col,
       (SELECT col FROM t WHERE col  = outer_q.col) new_col,
       (SELECT col FROM (Something more complex) WHERE ... = outer_q.col) new_col,
from t outer_q where col = 2;
```

So we now have the same level of "interiority".

*EDIT:* to answer the updated question, there is a little adaptation needed:

```
WITH t(col) AS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 2 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 3 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 4 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 5 FROM dual
),
t1(amount, col) AS
(
  SELECT 100, 2 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 200, 3 FROM dual
)
SELECT col,
     (SELECT col FROM t WHERE col = outer_q.col) new_col,
     (SELECT SUM(amount)
      FROM
          (SELECT col, col amount FROM t  -- row is (1, 1), then (2, 2) etc
           UNION ALL
           SELECT col, amount FROM t1     -- row is (2, 100), then (3, 200) etc
          )
      WHERE col = outer_q.col
     ) newest_col -- gives 102 as it takes whole `SUM`
FROM t outer_q
WHERE col = 2;
```

The part to understand is in the innermost query: you want to sum both the column and the amount value, so you repeat the `col` value as if it was an amount.

Another way to obtain the same result (with more performance, I guess) would be to sum `col` and `amount` on the same row:

```
WITH t(col) AS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 2 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 3 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 4 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 5 FROM dual
),
t1(amount, col) AS
(
  SELECT 100, 2 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 200, 3 FROM dual
)
SELECT col,
     (SELECT col FROM t WHERE col = outer_q.col) new_col,
     (SELECT SUM(all_amount)
      FROM
          (SELECT col, col + amount all_amount FROM t1)
      WHERE col = outer_q.col
     ) newest_col -- gives 315 as it takes whole `SUM`
FROM t outer_q
WHERE col = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the above sample, you're perfect, I've updated the question for some more sample data, please check

Answer (score 2):

The inner query fails because you tried to push the outer_q.col reference two levels down. Correlated query goes only 1 level down

Reference: [http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1853075500346799932](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1853075500346799932)